# fix net::err_unknown_url_scheme whatsapp link on flutter webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web, whatsapp

Please I want to know how to launch WhatsApp in the Flutter `webview` app or launch WhatsApp from the browser in Flutter, have used many codes with no errors but they do not work.Am using mac m1
and vscode

```
import 'package:coinpaga/Connectivity_Provider.dart';
import 'package:coinpaga/services/local_notification_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:colorful_safe_area/colorful_safe_area.dart';

///  Receive message when app is in background solution for on 
message
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)async{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  LocalNotificationServices.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ConnectivityProvider(),
      child: HomePage(),
    )
  ],
  child:MaterialApp(
  title: 'coinpaga',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: ColorfulSafeArea(
    color: HexColor("#2e2a42"),
    top: true,
    bottom: false,
    left: false,
    right: false,
    child: HomePage(),
  )
),
);
}
}
```

Home.dart

```
   import 'package:coinpaga/Connectivity_Provider.dart';
   import 'package:coinpaga/no_internet.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
   import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // ignore: unused_field
  final _flutterwebview = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  HomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<ConnectivityProvider>(context, listen: 
false).startMonitoring();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return pageUI();
  }
 @override
  void dispose() {
   _flutterwebview.dispose();
 super.dispose();
 }
}
  Widget pageUI() {
 return Consumer<ConnectivityProvider>(
builder: (context, model, child) {
  return model.isOnline 
? WebviewScaffold(
url: 'https://coinpaga.com',

withLocalStorage: true,
withJavascript: true,
scrollBar: false,
initialChild: Center(child: Text('Loading...')),
  ) : NoInternet();
 },
   );
}

  // ignore: camel_case_types
 class _flutterwebview {
  static void dispose() {}
   }
```

Please help me go through it.

Comment: where is your webview code? I can't find it

Comment: here is the webview code

Comment: no `navigationDelegate` on `flutter_webview_plugin`. Try this library https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter and use navigation delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), then I use this code to launch whatsapp on flutter webview and works.

```
WebView(
                initialUrl: getUrl(_url),
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
                  if (request.url
                      .startsWith('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone')) {
                    print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                    List<String> urlSplitted = request.url.split("&text=");
              
                    String phone = "0123456789";
                    String message =
                        urlSplitted.last.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ");
                   
                    await _launchURL(
                        "https://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");
                    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                  }

                  print('allowing navigation to $request');
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                },
          
              )
```

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: @SaliuSheriff pls attach your code to the question. not here

Comment: Please can you send a tutorial

Comment: am new to developing

Comment: @SaliuSheriff attach the code you've tried. And I will give you a suggestion.

Comment: @SaliuSheriff refer https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c

Comment: here is my main.dart file

Answer (score 12):

```
String text = "Hello World !! Hey There";
String url = "https://wa.me/?text=${Uri.encodeFull(text)}";
if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),
mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This work for me using the package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
launchUrl(
  Uri.parse(
    "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=YOUR_PHONE_NO"),
    mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to launch URLs.

You can give `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=(phone_number)` URL to launch.

For the launching the WhatsApp Website use `launch('https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=(phone_number)')`

Make sure you give your country code without (+).

Comment: launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);

Answer (score 2):

Actually I use this code:

```
onPressed: () async {
  String appUrl;
  String phone = '+989125272xxx'; // phone number to send the message to
  String message = 'Hi guys,'; // message to send
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    appUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}"; // URL for Android devices
  } else {
    appUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phone=${Uri.parse(message)}"; // URL for non-Android devices
  }

  // check if the URL can be launched
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(appUrl))) {
    // launch the URL
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(appUrl));
  } else {
    // throw an error if the URL cannot be launched
    throw 'Could not launch $appUrl';
  }
},
```

but it is very important, you need to add the **QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES** permission to work fine on **Android 12 or higher** devices to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file. This permission allows your app to query all installed packages on the device, including WhatsApp.

Add the following line inside the manifest tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: Thats totally wrong to do so! Google strictly discourage using this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en . Your app will get rejected if you do not have a good reason!

Answer (score 0):

To launch URLs, you can add the latest version of the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package from pub.

```
var phonenumber = snapshot.data?.whatsApp ?? "";
        
if (phonenumber != "") {
    phonenumber = phonenumber.replaceAll("+", "");
        
    var whatsAppUrl = Uri.parse("https://wa.me/$phonenumber?text=Hello",);
    if (await launchUrl(whatsAppUrl, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
        throw Exception('Could not launch ${whatsAppUrl.path}');
    }
}
```